# Can't retrieve data from mysql to html template in django (PyCharm)

Tags: html, mysql, django, pycharm

I am hoping someone can help me here; been stuck for a while in this part of learning web development. I am using django in PyCharm community edition. Everything with Apache and MySQL seems to be working well. I am at the stage of making html templates and I am able to log data into MySQL databases. I wanted to retrieve data from a database into a template but it just does not work and I get a warning saying "Unresolved attribute reference '…' for class '…'" when defining a view in PyCharm. These are my files:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import AirplanePics # AirplanePics is a model

def pictures(request):
    obj = AirplanePics.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {
        'datax': obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'pictures.html')
```

In models, I tried a workaround that I read in this forum, but it just recognized 'objects' (in the views.py class) and removed the warning

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class AirplanePics(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

```
# models.py (with the workaround)

from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AirplanePics(BaseModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

I just want to be able to show the author (for example):

```
# pictures.html

<h1>{{datax.author}}</h1>
```

... but the page does not show anything when I run the server.
Also:

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .views import pictures, home

urlpatterns = [
    path('pictures/', pictures, name='pictures'),
    path('home/', home, name='home')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

why it is not getting displayed is, you are not passing the context to the template.

```
def pictures(request):
    obj = AirplanePics.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {
        'datax': obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'pictures.html', context)
```

once you delete the picture and create another, the id will be changed so it is better to call. Your first model is enough to do the job.

```
obj = AirplanePics.objects.first()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was that simple. Also thanks for the advice.